# Proof that $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists \delta>0$ s.t $\mu(\{x: f(x) > \delta\})>1-\epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory

Assume we have measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ with $\mu(X) = 1$. Let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be s.t $f>0$ a.e and $f$ is measurable. How do we show the property in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]
You need to assume $f$ is a measurable function. Let $B_n = \{x:\; 1/(n-1) \ge f(x) > 1/n\}$, with $B_1 = \{x: f(x) > 1\}$.
Then $B_n$ are disjoint measurable sets with $\bigcup_{n =1}^\infty B_n = \{x: f(x) > 0\}$.  By countable additivity $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(B_n) = \mu(\{x: f(x) > 0\}) = 1$.  That means
$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \mu(B_n) = 1$.  Use the definition of limit...

Comment: I dont think $\cup B_n = X$, since $f(x)$ can be negative for some $x$, but this $x$ is not in any $B_n$

Comment: I think this proof still should work, because the set of points for which $f(x) \leq 0$ is of measure $0$ and so we can just ignore them, even though $\cup B_n \neq X$.

Comment: @Naah omg yes I forgot the problem when looking at the proof :( Yeah it should work you're right!